# Flutter and DateTime : change the hour display

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I am using DateTime in a Flutter project and I would like to know ifs it possible with DateTime to modify the display of the hours, for example:

by default HH: mm: ss = 12:12:12
but I would like to display 12h 12mn 12s?

my code :

```
String heurearchive = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `DateFormat` like this.

```
DateFormat("HH'h' mm'mn' ss's'")
```

Answer (score 0):

[DateFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class will use as pattern what you tell to use, so if you write `DateFormat('HH:mm:ss')` then it will format as `HH:mm:ss`, to be as you expected try this way

```dart
DateFormat('HH\'h\' mm\'mn\' s\'s\'');
```

Others patterns can be found in docs

```
Symbol   Meaning                Presentation       Example
------   -------                ------------       -------
G        era designator         (Text)             AD
y        year                   (Number)           1996
M        month in year          (Text & Number)    July & 07
L        standalone month       (Text & Number)    July & 07
d        day in month           (Number)           10
c        standalone day         (Number)           10
h        hour in am/pm (1~12)   (Number)           12
H        hour in day (0~23)     (Number)           0
m        minute in hour         (Number)           30
s        second in minute       (Number)           55
S        fractional second      (Number)           978
E        day of week            (Text)             Tuesday
D        day in year            (Number)           189
a        am/pm marker           (Text)             PM
k        hour in day (1~24)     (Number)           24
K        hour in am/pm (0~11)   (Number)           0
z        time zone              (Text)             Pacific Standard Time
Z        time zone (RFC 822)    (Number)           -0800
v        time zone (generic)    (Text)             Pacific Time
Q        quarter                (Text)             Q3
'        escape for text        (Delimiter)        'Date='
''       single quote           (Literal)          'o''clock
```

Comment: was using `String heurearchive = new DateFormat("hhAmmBssC").format(DateTime.now()).replaceAll("A", "h ").replaceAll("B", "mn ").replaceAll("C", "s");` ... 

Comment: Not recommended.  DateFormat() page specifically says all alphabetic chars are reserved for future expansion.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.
Thanks Jigar Patel: this is exactly what I wanted.
I had seen this method on the internet but when I tested it it did not work. I think it was a bit late and my brain is lost with all these quotes !!!